# python for loop for creating a 2D array form 2 1D array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to use python for getting vibrational partition function at different temperature. I have two 1D array like: `freq=[100,150,200]`(This is actually read form a .dat file) and `Temp=np.arange(273.,973.,25)`.
Now, qvib=product over freq for a particular temperature`(1/1-exp(-h*nu/kb/T))`. My for loop is:

```
for i in range(len(T)):
 for j in range(len(freq)):
  q[i][j]=1/(1-np.exp(-h*freq[j]/kb/T[i]))
   Q[i]=np.prod(q[i][:])
```

I am using python for two to three days only. I even don't know all the in line operation of python. I have two question:
1) Can i do it without using for loop (like using only sum or no.prod)
2) My for loop is not working. I searched on internet but couldn't found any good for loop reference for this type of mathematical operation.
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'q' is not defined


I think i need to declare q and Q but i don't know how to declare them.

Comment: what are q and Q supposed to be?

Comment: q=vibrational contribution of individual frequency   

Q=product of all the vibrational contribution of those individual frequency at a particular temperature.

Comment: You must always declare variables before you try to use them and if you want all the changes reflected make sure they are defined outside the loops. If you add a small sample of input and expected output it will make your question easier to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to at least define `Q` as an empty array the same length as your temperature array before you can assign to it.:

```
Q = np.empty(len(T))
```

Better is:

```
for i in range(len(T)):
    q = 1/(1-np.exp(-h*freq/kb/T[i]))     
Q = np.prod(q)
```

But the really nice thing about NumPy is the ability to do away with Python loops altogether:

```
Q = np.prod(1/(1-np.exp(-h*freq[:, None]/kb/T)), axis=0)
```

Comment: Now, It is working fine. Only problem was declaring the variables.Thanks